# How can I list all existing workspaces in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How can I list all existing workspaces in JupyterLab?

I know that one can view the current workspace name in the URL:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you found other solutions (for instance jupyter-native)?

Comment: @meduz no~~~~~~

Answer (score 11):

When you create a workspace, this creates a file in `~/.jupyter/lab/workspaces`. The name of your workspace is in the `['metadata']['id']` key of the corresponding JSON file.

a simple code to list all workspaces is therefore:

```py
import os, glob, json
for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], ".jupyter/lab/workspaces/*")):
     with open (fname, "r") as read_file:
         print (json.load(read_file)['metadata']['id'])
```

For convenience, I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/laurentperrinet/780e73753f7abdcf73dfefdbfbb639be) with that bit of code. I have also added some cosmetics to directly generate the different URLs:

```sh
$ list_workspaces.py -u
http://10.164.5.234:8888/lab
http://10.164.5.234:8888/lab/workspaces/BBCP
http://10.164.5.234:8888/lab/workspaces/blog
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable workspaces, i.e. limit the workspace creation process to just one workspace?

Comment: to limit to one workspace, do *not* use them but just the http://localhost:8888/lab URI

Comment: I have updated the script in the gist which allows you to use that in a script - generates for instance a list of URLs which you can click on (in a *modern* terminal emulator)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of auto-x workspaces, polluting the list.

Answer (score 8):

I think you could try

`ls ~/.jupyter/lab/workspaces`

Each time u create a new workspace, there will be a corresponding file generated here. More detailed docs are [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#managing-workspaces-ui)

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, workspace files are located at `~/.jupyter/lab/workspaces`. Each workspace is represented by a `.jupyterlab-workspace`, which is actually just a JSON file.

If you have the CLI tool `jq` installed, the following one-liner gives you a quick list of workspaces:

```
cat ~/.jupyter/lab/workspaces/* | jq -r '.metadata.id'
```

Sample output:

```
/lab
/lab/workspaces/aaaaaaaaaaaa
/lab/workspaces/xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: As a side note: you do not need to use `cat`: you can simply do:  `< $JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR/lab/workspaces/* jq -r ".metadata.id"` (you do not need to set `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR`, of course)

Answer (score 1):

With most basic shell commands:

```
grep metadata ~/.jupyter/lab/workspaces/* | sed -e 's/"/ /g' | awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Output will look like:

```
/lab
/lab/workspaces/auto-x
/lab/workspaces/foo
```